# C# MVC for single page website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The way I understand C# MVC ASP.NET is that I have multiple subpages for different data.

Eg,

- mysite.com/Home
- mysite.com/Car
- mysite.com/AboutMe

For that I would have 3 models, Home, Car and AboutMe and 3 Controllers.

What if I would like to have a one page website where you can just scroll from top to bottom. 
How do I accomplish that with MVC?
Would I make only 1 Controller? If so, how do I from the Controller output the 3 models that I need?

Comment: Try to use search and tutorials like this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs

Comment: I suggest that you start looking at Partial Views which would allow you to host multiple sections to a master page each with their own associated model,

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand this concept if you are coming from a Web Forms experience, you need to learn some basic tutorials. [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1) , [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575397/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-MVC-for)

Comment: Use the template: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in multiple different ways in MVC.
You can Visit this: [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

You can use a single ViewModel that would contain your HOme,Car,AboutMe Data.
You can also use partial views.
Here i am going to explain you using a single Viewmodel approach.

In your ViewModel:

```
public class SingleViewModel
{
        public List<Home>  ListHome {get; set;}

        public List<Car>   ListCar {get; set;}

        public List<AboutMe> ListAboutMe {get; set;}

}
```

In Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

//you need to populate your viewmodel with data from database
SingleViewModel model=new SingleViewModel();

model.ListHome=GetHomeData().ToList();
model.ListCar=GetCarData().ToList();
model.AboutMe=GetAboutMeData().ToList();

       //pass your model to view

        return View(model);
    }
```

In View

```
@model <Proj.Model.SingleViewModel>
```

//
now you can populate data from your model here
//

Comment: I dont get it why would you have `List<Home>` list of Home objects, its not that u will have several home pages or that 1 view expects more then 1 home object representing home model. Also `model.ListHome=GetHomeData().ToList();` implies you are loosing strong types that are naturally coming trough MVC binding.

Comment: Also you are populating all 3 collections every time index page is accessed which makes no sense, you need different methods on same controller depending on which page needs to be displayed and populate their respective model.

Comment: Even tho accepted as correct answer i strongly advise anyone reading this to consult documentation as this is terrible example of MVC usage.

Comment: @MladenOršolić By List<Home> it does not mean multiple home pages,it just means multiple data of 'home' type. Let for ex you want to display following data in your page Name=Home1,location=street 1,image=image1 then Name=Home2,location=street2,image=image2,,there is multiple home data so you could just add it to a list and display on a view. There are other serveral ways by which you can do this like you can use ienumerable instead of a List. It just depends on your requirement.

Comment: The question was about to load data of all three on a single page , and as i said it all depends on your requirements asp.net mvc uses an ORM(EntityFramework) , which uses lazy loading by default , if you have a requirement where the same data is populated again and again then populating view without lists is an headache , your ienumerable will flood your database with hits so in that case you have to use list.

Comment: _The question was about to load data of all three on a single page_ nope it was not as it wouldnt make any sense, why load all 3 pages when calling one. _asp.net mvc uses an ORM(EntityFramework)_ again wrong, it can but it doesn't necessarily. Further more i, in my solution never used IEnumerable but strong type binding.

Comment: Just FYI Single page application <> loading all at once!

Comment: Also OP wants to display a home page (other pages in scroll down sequence) not a list of _Name=Home1,location=street 1,image=image1 then Name=Home2,location=street2,image=image2_ ...

Answer (score 3):

You can have a parent object representing Model, that will contain objects for page 1,2,3 and in your views you will reference fields from the model just by prefixing standard reference with name of the instance of parent object.
Also you would need 1 controller then.

```
public class PageModel // parent model
{
    // page models
    public HomeModel HomeModel {get; set;} 
    public CarModel CarModel {get; set;}
    public AboutMeModel AboutMeModel {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different solutions for that. Basically MVC is also good for single page applications or landing pages.

But now to your quetion about the view models. You could create a "aggregate" model that contains all three models:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
        public HomeModel HomeModel {get; set;}

        public CarModel CarModel {get; set;}

        public AboutMeModel AboutMeModel {get; set;}

}
```

As second solution: you could also add these models to the `ViewBag` in the controller action and access them on the view (then you don't need the MainViewModel).

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.HomeModel = new HomeModel();
        ViewBag.CarModel = new CarModel();
        ViewBag.AboutMeModel = new AboutMeModel();
        return View();
    }
```